# Full page, full width table of contents using ieeeconf class

Tags: table-of-contents, templates, ieee-style, ieeeconf

I'm trying to make a full page, full width table of contents. I'm using following class:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}
```

and every time I try to use `\tableofcontents`, I get a half paged table.

How to make it full page and width?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Can you post a small, fully-working example, to demonstrate this behavior?

Comment: Welcome to SE! Try: `\onecolumn\\tableofcontents\twocolumn`  . Maybe will this help.

Comment: @Zarko there's one \ too much and one effect is a pagebreak after the TOC

Comment: @naphaneal, I see. This is typing error (my keyboard is very old and inclined to bouncing...). Correct is `\onecolumn\tableofcontents\twocolumn`.

Comment: Completing Steven's comment: A a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: possible solution can be found here: http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-onecolabs.html but the vertical indentation is bad if simply C&P'ed, as the first section is put almost inside the TOC

Comment: Thank you! I am extremely new at this and I'm sorry if I'm not doing it all right. @Zarko it did work and it made my table of contents the width of the page! Thank you very much. I was wondering however if there is anyway to also make it the full length of the page?

Comment: @user102426, I convert my comments in one answer with three cases of article layouts.

Comment: why would you try to put a TOC in a conference paper?

Answer (score 2):

From your question is not very clear (to me), how your document (article?) should look:

- as one column article: in this case you should declare

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference, onecolumn]{ieeeconf}
% other used packages and title definition

\begin{document}
%title, abstract etc
\tableofcontents
% rest of article 
\end{document}
```

- as combined layout where the `\tableofcontents` is in one column, the following rest of document in standard `twocolum`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}
% other used packages and title definition

\begin{document}
%title, abstract etc
\onecolumn
\tableofcontents
\twocolumn
% rest of article is in two column
\end{document}
```

- as combined layout where for the `\tableofcontents` is reserved whole first page in one column layout and the following rest of pages in`twocolum` layout:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}
% other used packages and title definition

\begin{document}
%title, abstract etc
\onecolumn
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\twocolumn
% rest of article is in two column
\end{document}
```

For testing above cases I need from you a Minimal Working Example (MWE). See, which of above cases you actually like to have.

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak the class choices:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{IEEEconf}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\author{A. Uthor}
\title{Title}

\twocolumn[
  \maketitle
  \tableofcontents
  \bigskip\bigskip
]

\section{First}
\subsection{Hello}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Second}
\subsection{Hello}
\lipsum[3-4]

\section{Third}
\subsection{Hello}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Fourth}
\subsection{Hello}
\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]